# Rails 3.0.0.beta2 problem with Rails::Generators::GeneratedAttribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I am trying to use the rails3 branch of Nifty Generators by Ryan Bates.  Now I've used this gem before with beta1 and its worked, but after upgrading to beta2 I've been getting a very wierd error.

```
lib/generators/nifty/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb:35:in `block in initialize': uninitialized constant Rails::Generators::GeneratedAttribute (NameError)
```

The peice of code where this happens:

```
args_for_c_m.each do |arg|
  if arg == '!'
    options[:invert] = true
  elsif arg.include?(':')
    @model_attributes << Rails::Generators::GeneratedAttribute.new(*arg.split(':'))
  else
    @controller_actions << arg
    @controller_actions << 'create' if arg == 'new'
    @controller_actions << 'update' if arg == 'edit'
  end
end
```

Now I've seen GeneratedAttribute used in many gems before, so I'm confused on why its breaking.  I'm not sure, but I think this has to do with beta2.

So my question is this a Rails problem of something on my end?  If it is on my end any ideas what I have may done wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably either a beta2 bug or rails doesn't load that module automatically anymore. Try adding

```
require 'rails/generators/generated_attribute'
```

Comment: I went to the rails console and did a quick "require 'rails/generators/generated_attribute'", it returned nil.  So I don't think this will work either.