# uninitialized constant Rails::Generators (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I'm updating the code for a generator that I wrote, but has been working fine until now.

When I simply rue the command

```
bundle exec rails g
```

I get the following error

```
/Users/mpierc200/projects/prototype_conflux/vendor/gems/itrc_client_files_generator-1.0.13/lib/itrc_client_files_generator.rb:6:in `<top (required)>':
uninitialized constant Rails::Generators (NameError)
```

The offending line is

```
class ItrcClientFilesGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
```

My Rails version is

```
Rails 3.1.9
```

ruby version is

```
ruby 1.9.3p194
```

Comment: Isn't this based off code [you wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500469/how-to-implement-generators-for-a-plugin-located-at-the-lib-plugin-name-dire)?

Comment: yes, the offending line is in a file I wrote.

Comment: Try `require 'rails/generators/generated_attribute'`. Based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2594602/403664).

Comment: Hmm. Going through the [rails code for 3.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators/base.rb) it looks right. Why not try just `require rails/generators`?

Comment: D'oh.  I thought I had tried that.  I looked up the class documentation, and tried requiring the file the doc said the class was in.  @d_ethier, your suggestion worked!

Comment: @d_ethier write up your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it.  Then the question won't appear as unanswered. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like the Rails generator modules were pulled out and not automatically loaded at some point during Rails 3 development. This is probably for good reasons.

You have to include them in custom generators:

```
require 'rails/generators'

class ItrcClientFilesGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
  # Fancy generator code here
end
```